# no me identifica pillow la imagen

Tags: python, matplotlib, pillow

`Imagen = Image.open('./dog.jpg')`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

```
UnidentifiedImageError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-00df69f0fea0> in <module>
----> 1 Imagen = Image.open('./dog.jpg')

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2860         warnings.warn(message)
   2861     raise UnidentifiedImageError(
-> 2862         "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
   2863     )
   2864 

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file './dog.jpg'
```

Comment: ese ./ que ven ahi lo use tambien sin ese y no me funcionl la carga de la imagen ahi se puede notar que el archivo si existe

Comment: No es porque no encuentre el archivo, eso daría un error `FileNotFoundError`,  el error `UnidentifiedImageError` indica que no es capaz de determinar el formato de la imagen, una causa muy simple es que tu imagen no sea realmente jpg como indica la extensión o el fichero esté corrupto...

Comment: pero lo corri en colab y automaticamente me corrio